# What are the evolutionary advantages to have epicanthic folds?

Tags: evolution, humans, fantasy-races, hominid, appearance

In my world, there are sixteen species that form together the living species of the *Homo* genus: anatomically modern humans (*Homo sapiens* *sensu stricto*), merfolk, angels, demons, ogres, giants, halflings, dwarves, goblins, gnomes, elves, trolls, orcs, therianthropes, vampires, and wizards (the last fifteen are still humans, just not *H. sapiens s. stricto*).

All these species can interbreed together, and their descendants tend to be less fertile than full-blooded anatomically modern humans (what I mean is hybrid humans are less likely to have multiple births, females have a higher risk of polycystic ovary syndrome, and males have a higher risk of oligospermia, but they can still reproduce).

Some of these species overwhelmingly have epicanthic folds: this is the case for 80% of ogres, 90% of orcs, 60% of halflings, 75% of trolls, 55% of gnomes, and 85% of wizards.

In the case of other species, this physical feature is rarer: 40% of dwarfs, 10% of giants, 25% of merfolk, 30% of demons, 15% of angels, 35% of therianthropes, 20% of vampires, 5% of elves, and 45% of goblins have epicanthic folds.

So, I wonder what evolutionary advantages would lead to epicanthic folds in some species belonging to the *Homo* genus.

Note: since my story is a satire against both racism and speciesism, all my species have both good individuals, and evil individuals.

Comment: Not everything has to have an evolutionary advantage. Most mutations are neutral, or mildly deleterious.

Comment: Found an answer on Reddit, explanation given there has to do with the shape of the nose, the evolutionary advantages either having to do with cold climate, or with desert conditions (sand, wind)  https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/hiws9/why_do_asian_people_have_slanted_eyes/

Comment: (1) Epicanthic folds are present in all known human populations, with varying frequencies of occurrence. (2) The question needs to explain what exactly is unclear in *"the exact evolutionary function and origin of epicanthic folds remains unknown; scientific explanations include either random variation and selection (presumably sexual selection), or possible adaption to cold, desert environment and/or high levels of ultraviolet light"*. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Epicanthic_fold&oldid=1063303029#Possible_evolutionary_function))

Comment: @Goodies that's a slightly terrible thread, to say the least. Assuming weather has any bearing on it at all seems like the sort of adaptationist nonsense you'd get from someone who hasn't looked at the sheer range of biomes that this particular feature pops up in, and who starts with the idea that _everything_ has to have an evolutionary advantage.

Comment: I apologize for downvoting, but (a) you don't explain what an epicanthic fold is, forcing me to go look it up and (b) you appear to have done no research for why it exists (from an evolutionary perspective) in humanity today - despite that answer being the most obvious answer to your question.

Comment: This question is either absolutely bonkers or absolute genius. In a world with sixteen species of humans, some small as a doormouse and some big as a truck, some with wings and some with two inches of blubber, they all have the exact same eye structure enough for you to be worried about something as minor as whether the upper eyelid is visible? Can a dog have epicanthic folds? Or is this part of your "satire against both racism and speciesism" and your world contains people fixating on such trivial things as an indicator of race? Hmmm?

Answer (score 3):

**It makes everyone look younger!**

Scientific consesus nowadays?  None, which means theoricrafting is free.
so let's dig into human lore.

Hear me out, it might just be sexual selection, if you want, later I will post some stats here but apparently all races prefer eastern asian women.

Why? is everyone just a yellow feticist? Maybe, or the most realistic answer could be  that more often than not male mammals are attracted to youthfull and healthy looking features. Lighter skin tones and epicanthic folds are incredibly common in children of all human ethnicities.

Why are some parts of the world having a majority of people with epicanthic fold? Simple sexual selection.

okcupid showing racial bias in dating;
[image]

[Also dropping here data gathred by facebook](https://qz.com/149342/the-uncomfortable-racial-preferences-revealed-by-online-dating/) and Rudder's research on the matter [1](https://books.google.it/books?hl=en&lr=&id=-xEcAwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PT10&dq=rudder%20racial%20preferences&ots=yeI-65lrcB&sig=MhpPsXEb9vAVYKzup41hRvd_waY#v=onepage&q=rudder%20racial%20preferences&f=false)

As you can see, from the eyes it is really hard to judge their age, and gives off a sense of ''cuteness'' or more scientifically speaking ''neoteny''
[image]

"netotenic is always beneficial. Common view: neotenic properties help sexual selection, because a younger partner will yield healthier children - on average - than an older partner." -@Goodies

Comment: Very funny *"a selection that makes women more appealing and ironically it also makes men more unappealing, as it gives off an aura of being too youthful, apparently human females are mostly attracted to men that don't look too young"* LOL hold on, we're talking physical attraction, not marriage perspectives.. I think your statement is either a very old (50s-60s) misconception, invented by wishful thinking older researchers, and it was also widely used as a sexist disqualification of women's intentions ("they are only in for the money")

Comment: @Goodies what does male physical attraction have anything to do with ''they are only in for the money'' ? at most it literally says the opposite don't you think ? that they are in for the sex appeal lol... I have no idea about your line of reasoning, please explain how you've got to that point

Comment: It might've been better if you provided some links to research papers to substantiate your answer. It would've also been nicer if you could use a bit more neutral language.

Comment: @Otkin ok will fetch the links, what do you mean with neutral? gender neutral?

Comment: Less speculation, more facts. Fewer subjective statements. It is also worth mentioning that the ability to differentiate faces (including age approximation) depends on familiarity with various shapes of faces. Asians living in Asian countries have difficulty distinguishing Caucasian faces, just like Caucasians often struggle to distinguish Asian faces.

Comment: LOL @PythonProgrammersaresouless for women, the minimum preferred age of a partner is *also* younger, as counts for men. The maximum preferred age however differs, women seem to *accept* older partners more easy than men do.. but that won't say their preference is older men.. the difference could also be explained by men having a specific preference for young women, ref for minmax data,  https://www.sexandpsychology.com/blog/2017/10/4/do-we-want-partners-who-are-older-or-younger-than-us-heres-what-the-research-says/

Comment: @Goodies yeah still doesn't change that a 24 yo man is still young but if he looks like a 16yo he will be perceived as infantile, while a 24 yo women looking like 16yo is considered youthfull by most men.... youtfull vs infantile, that's the difference. Age is just a number, I'm talking about appearance here

Comment: @Otkin ''familiarity with various shapes of faces. Asians living in Asian countries have difficulty distinguishing Caucasian faces, just like Caucasians often'' I don't buy this belief that different races don't see one another as aliens, and it's not like I've never seen an asian in my life or asians have never seen white people in their life.... there's Tv, internet, globalization.... I live in rome, There's a lot's of folk with epicanthic folds in here, we have all kind of folks from all kind of places in central cities like Rome, New York, Hong Kong...

Comment: @PythonProgrammersaresouless I don't think you're really wrong, but the way you stated it made me laugh. Neoteny could indeed be part of sexual selection, the fact women's faces  and bodies tend to have neotenic properties anyway supports  the asymmetry you have stated. But you can't say "women prefer older men". It is a statistical thing, rather than a property. Lots of women fancy younger men, it also depends on role patterns (culture) and what role men and women have in relationships.

Comment: @Goodies well that's kind of rephrasing what i've said... I said ''apparently human females are mostly attracted to men that don't look **TOO** young'' and it was in the original answer before editing it. I can edit it with some suggestions....

Comment: @PythonProgrammersaresouless I'll reconsider (swap) my downvote.. Maybe you could shift the focus from gender analysis and gender differences and leave the images, to make the answer more neutral, or shorter. Gender does not really matter, netotenic is always beneficial. Common view: neotenic properties help sexual selection, because a younger partner will yield healthier children - on average - than an older partner.

Comment: @Otkin adding more to that, there's plenty of cities in italy where the percentage of Chinese folk alone reaches 6% or 7% of the total population,  not counting all the japanese folk, thai, indonesians and so on....Globablization is everywhere.... you can't say anymore ''all asians look the same because you are not used to seeing them'' it's not  1920 anymore. I'm just as used to seeing asian faces as any other face, same goes for anyone living in a populated country, or populated city.

Comment: I know you aren't doing a scientific study here, but there are a couple of leaps in this answer that leave me pretty unconvinced. 1) Your data is from predominantly western sources - this means we've a lot of cultural baggage to contend with. Stereotypes and other misconceptions play heavily here. 2) Even if there is an inherent biological preference there is nothing to say its the eyes that are the reason for it. The list of assumptions is long enough that, especially for a world with giants and wizards, I feel we may as well have gone with a purely otherworldly concept.

Comment: For me this edit is ok, the text is about epicanthic folds as neotenic properties now, influencing sexual selection.. which is not disputed, ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection_in_humans Swapped my vote :)

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-race_effect).

Comment: You are right. In the picture on the right I cannot tell who is the baby and who is the mother. They both look so young!

Comment: Where did the talk of telling people of different races apart come from? I cannot find it in the question or in the edit history.